# Trouble with nextJs showing data based on my search parameters

Tags: next.js

This is my code:

```js
import Results from "components/Results";
import React from "react";

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const keyword = context.query.search;
  console.log("keyword " + keyword);
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}&query=${keyword}&language=en-US&include_adult=false`
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  const results = data.results;

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("oops movie not found");
  }
  return {
    props: { results },
  };
}

export default function searchTerm({ results }) {
  console.log(results);

  return (
    <div>
      {results && results.length === 0 && (
        <h1 className="text-red-700 text-center">No movie found</h1>
      )}
      {results && <Results results={results} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the console gives me undefined

Comment: Add a console log before returning props {results} and check its value

Comment: Silly me. I have solved by changing context params to be searchTerm instead of search because my dynamic page name is named searchTerm.